# CURSOR and RECORDS PL SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have an academic project with a book store database. I am asked to prompt the user for a number of best sellers and then display the results using a cursor with a record.

I can't seem to figure out how integrate the user input when asking the cursor to order that many results.

Any ideas or insights are greatly appreciated!

```
accept best_sllrno prompt 'Please enterthe amount of best sellers:'


DECLARE
    best_sllrno number;
    CURSOR bst_cur IS
    SELECT bk_books.title, bk_books.book_id, bk_books.year_publd, bk_books.isbn, bk_books.list_price, bk_order_details.quantity
    FROM bk_books
        JOIN bk_order_details
            ON bk_books.book_id = bk_order_details.book_id
    ORDER BY bk_order_details.order_id DESC;
bk_record bst_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN bst_cur;
FETCH bst_cur INTO bk_record;
CLOSE bst_cur;


END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on Scott's schema (ran on Oracle 11gXE); you should be able to rewrite it so that it matches your tables. Could I do that? Sure, but - you'd better write your own homework.

Basically, it uses the *accepted* value in cursor's `WHERE` clause, limiting the number of returned rows.

I chose not to explicitly declare a cursor because I should then: declare a cursor variable, open the cursor, loop through it, take care about exiting the loop and close the cursor. Using cursor FOR loop, most of the *dirty* job is done by Oracle.

```
SQL> accept par_how_many prompt 'How many rows do you want? '
How many rows do you want? 5
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select d.dname, e.ename
  3                  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  4                  where rownum <= &par_how_many
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.dname ||' - '|| cur_r.ename);
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
RESEARCH - SMITH
SALES - ALLEN
SALES - WARD
RESEARCH - JONES
SALES - MARTIN

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```